# Apache with Passenger doesn't load Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, apache, passenger

I'm developing a Rails app and am trying to configure the web server it's deployed on.
My problem is that the page doesn't load.

In Apache's `error.log` there are **no errors** and in my app's `log/production.log` only the line(s) `Connecting to database specified by database.yml` appears.

I have no index.html in app's public folder and the application works fine in the development environment.

I'm using an Amazon instance with Ubuntu 12.04 and I've installed ruby through RVM.
In my httpd.conf I have:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17
PassengerRuby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby
```

Apache starts without errors.

Below there is my `sites-available/default`:

```
# other virtualhosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my_app.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin mail@mail.com

    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/public_html/my_app/current/public

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/public_html/my_app/current/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

What should I do now to get passenger working?

Comment: Are there any clues in the `access.log?`

Comment: I think you're missing RailsEnv production (or whatever env)

Comment: @simonmorley shouldn't RailsEnv production be as default? Anyway, I tried it but nothing has changed

Comment: @FareeshVijayarangam no. it's completely blank

Comment: When you say page doesn't load do you get a 404, 500 or what error?? Have you got any other sites in that server? Stupid question, but have you definitely enabled that site?

Comment: @simonmorley Yes the site is enabled :) There are no error such as 404 or 500, simply an infinite loading-loop.
I'm now considering to unistall everything and reinstall the whole system.

Comment: If you're getting a loop, it should eventually stop and give you an error code. If the page just doesn't load - are you sure you've got f/w ports etc open. I'd create another virtual host on the server (make sure you remove the server name from default) and confirm apache is working with a simple html page. Then push your rails application. If you do have an endless loop, does your rails app have any redirects (like ssl)?

Comment: @simonmorley I answered my own question :) thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to reinstall Ruby and all the other stuff and moving to nginx.
*Finally* now I have all working (both in ngnix and apache).
This is what I've done, if someone cares:

### Ruby + Rails

Install ruby + rails via RVM

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

Load rvm in all opened shells

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Install gem

```
gem install passenger
```

### apache

Install apache and passenger module

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Copy these lines to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17
PassengerRuby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby
```

### nginx

Install nginx and passenger module

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Copy these lines to `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`

```
passenger_root /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17;
passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby;
```

Setup a script to allow you to control Nginx

```
wget -O init-deb.sh http://library.linode.com/assets/660-init-deb.sh
sudo mv init-deb.sh /etc/init.d/nginx
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx
sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f nginx defaults
```

You can now control Nginx with this script

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

### Final setup with nodejs

One of the other things you’ll want is Node.js. This will help you do the compiling of assets on deployments

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem the answer was in the unicorn.log file. It was a syntax error in a controller. You should look in the passenger log file